# Why doesn't this div fade out slowly?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohzumb2c/3/).

The modal fades in but not out, I've noticed if I add another css class

```
.out { opacity: 0 !important; }
```

and add that (rather than remove .in) it works. Why is this?

Comment: I think it is fading out, but you set its height to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a default height attribute to the `.fade` class. Currently, when the `.in` class gets removed, the modal immediately loses it's height before the fade out animation